# Word Jumble - 15 Letters

Tags: anagram

I came across a question in facebook, which asked to solve this word jumble! I wasted nearly 3 days, still couldn't get over it.

1st row provides the choices, and with this we have to fill the second row.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

> "HAPPY FIFTEENTH BIRTHDAY".